# While spinning vm, getting error on key vault secret

Tags: azure, azure-devops, terraform

Error: Error making Read request on Azure KeyVault Secret hc-az-zPOa9ltv8: keyvault.BaseClient#GetSecret: Failure responding to request: StatusCode=403 -- Original Error: autorest/azure: Service returned an error. Status=403 Code="Forbidden" Message="Client address is not authorized and caller is not a trusted service.\r\nClient address: 10.155.82.11 from unknown subnet\r\nCaller: appid=0d3471e8-8b8b-4daf-8766-10c0b653cb42;oid=1bea56a0-001d-49f8-9ec6-257a3dc35ed2;iss=https://sts.windows.net/15ccb6d1-d335-4996-b6f9-7b6925f08121/\r\nVault: hc-hub-key-vault;location=eastus" InnerError={"code":"ForbiddenByFirewall"}

on .terraform/modules/virtual_machine/modules/linux-disks/main.tf line 93, in data "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "vm_password":
93: data "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "vm_password" {

Comment: What is the code that generates this error?

Comment: data "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "vm_password" {
  name         = var.virtual_machine_name
  key_vault_id = var.key_vault_id != null ? var.key_vault_id : data.azurerm_key_vault.key_vault[0].id
}

Answer (score 1):

The information you need is actually in there. Access to the service was forbidden by the firewall. The client address (10.155.82.11) is from an unknown subnet.

> **Client address is not authorized and caller is not a trusted service**

Long story short: add the subnet as a valid network to access the Key Vault from. You can do so under Key Vault - Networking.

Comment: I have added the subnet as a valid network, but not able to add the IP address (10.155.82.11) under IPv4 address or CIDR. 
Is it because of private IP address?